# turtle graphics with functions

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am stuck, I need to draw a bin in turtle graphics using the width and length I get from `getDim()`, and apply the color to the can and bin from `getColor`. I don't understand how to call those functions in my `getDraw` function without having the user input repeatedly unnecessarily. I also need to fill up the bottom row of the bin with however many cans will fit with the given length, I rarely use turtle graphics so I am lost.

```
def main():
    candiam = 2.5
    height, width, length = getDim()
    numofcans = getCans()
    bincolor, cancolor = getColor()
    print ("The bin dimensions are: ",height," inches high", width," inches wide and", length," inches long")
    print ("You are recycling ",numofcans," cans.")



def getDim():

    height = int(input("Enter the bins height (40 to 60): "))
    width = int(input("Enter the bins width (40 to 60): "))
    length = int(input("Enter the bins length (40 to 60): "))
    while height not in range(40,61) and width not in range(40,61) and length not in range(40,61):
        print("You entered a wrong value")
        height = int(input("Enter the height (40 to 60: "))
        width = int(input("Enter the width(40 to 60: "))
        length = int(input("Enter the length (40 to 60: "))
    if height in range(40,61) and width in range(40,61) and length in range(40,61):
        return height, width, length

def getCans():

    cans = int(input("Enter the amount of cans (10,1000): "))
    if cans in range(10,1001):
        return cans
    while cans not in range(10,1001):
        cans = int(input("Invalid number, please enter the amount of cans (10,1000): "))
    return cans    

def getColor():
    bincolor = int(input("Color menu \n 1 = 'blue' \n 2 = 'red' \n 3 = 'green' \n 4 = 'magenta' \nPick the bin color: "))
    while bincolor not in range(1,5):
        bincolor = int(input("Color menu \n 1 = 'blue' \n 2 = 'red' \n 3 = 'green' \n 4 = 'magenta' \nPick the bin color: "))
    while bincolor in range(1,5):
        if bincolor == 1:
            bincolor = "blue"
        elif bincolor == 2:
            bincolor = "red"
        elif bincolor == 3:
            bincolor = "green"
        elif bincolor == 4:
            bincolor = "magenta"

    cancolor = int(input("Color menu \n 1 = 'blue' \n 2 = 'red' \n 3 = 'green' \n 4 = 'magenta' \nPick the can color: "))
    while cancolor not in range(1,5):
        cancolor = int(input("Color menu \n 1 = 'blue' \n 2 = 'red' \n 3 = 'green' \n 4 = 'magenta' \nPick the can color: "))

    while cancolor in range(1,5):
        if cancolor == 1:
            cancolor = "blue"
        elif cancolor == 2:
            cancolor = "red"
        elif cancolor == 3:
            cancolor = "green"
        elif cancolor == 4:
            cancolor = "magenta"
        return bincolor, cancolor


def drawBin():


main()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

save the color you get back and the dimensions you get back and pass those back into draw bin ... `getColor` and  `getDim` both are explicitly to get input from the user... that is all they do ... Im not sure what you would expect if not user input

also the second while loop in getColor does nothing dont use it

```
def getColor():
    bincolor = int(input("Color menu \n 1 = 'blue' \n 2 = 'red' \n 3 = 'green' \n 4 = 'magenta' \nPick the bin color: "))
    while bincolor not in range(1,5):
        bincolor = int(input("Color menu \n 1 = 'blue' \n 2 = 'red' \n 3 = 'green' \n 4 = 'magenta' \nPick the bin color: "))

    if bincolor == 1:
        bincolor = "blue"
    elif bincolor == 2:
        bincolor = "red"
    elif bincolor == 3:
        bincolor = "green"
    elif bincolor == 4:
        bincolor = "magenta"
```